# Thread.Abort() when running a debug app hosted in Visual Studio vs. running it directly

Tags: .net, multithreading, mutex

We have a thread in which, when we externally call Thread.Abort(), a ThreadAbortException is caught because we have some cleanup to do. In particular, a Mutex is requested. This crashes when running the application in debug mode outside of Visual Studio, but when hosted in Visual Studio, all runs fine. I heard the garbage collector runs differently when hosted vs. when not hosted. Could that have something to do with threads ? The error thrown is a buffer overrun.

Thanks !

Comment: We don't know, the call stcks we gather are all in the Microsoft DLLs, we have trouble figuring out the exact context on all threads.

Comment: The purpose of this thread really is to gather people's comments on what the difference is when running attached to a debugger or not.

Comment: Obligatory note: You shouldn't use `Thread.Abort()` at all. It's a nasty beast and dis-advised by everyone, including MSDN

Comment: @Ssebu - If the point of the question is to ask about differences, you should ask that question. If you want help with your specific issue(s) more information on your problem would be helpful. What dlls are the errors in, what are the stack traces, is the repro always stable and consistent?

Comment: A buffer overflow?  That requires a stack trace of the exception to diagnose, you'll have to post it.  With unmanaged code debugging and the Microsoft symbol server enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As Henk already pointed out, don't call `Thread.Abort`. Ever.

I have some information [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/02/q-should-i-set-variables-to-null-to.html) about how the garbage collector works differently in different situations. However, I believe that GC is the same for running a Debug build in or out of the debugger.

If you want other questions answered, you'll need to post more info. "Crashed" is not a descriptive term; does the application suddenly exit, or bring up a dialog you wrote, or bring up Windows Error Reporting? Similarly, I'm not familiar with a "buffer overrun" exception; for an exception, please post the exception type, message, and complete stack trace.